# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 6.1.8 $L^p$ spaces

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces

> Problem 6.1.8 - Suppose $\mu(X) = 1$ and $f\in L^p$ for some $p > 0$, so that $f\in L^q$ for $0 < q < p$.
>
> a.) $\log\|f\|_{q}\geq \int \log |f|$
>
> b.) $\left(\int |f|^{q} - 1\right)/q \geq \log \|f\|_{q}$, and $\left( \int |f|^q - 1\right)/q \rightarrow \int \log |f|$ as $q\rightarrow 0$
>
> c.) $\lim\limits_{q\rightarrow 0}\|f\|_{q} = \exp\left(\int \log |f|\right)$

Attempted proof a.) We know that, $$\|f\|_{q} = \left[\int|f|^q d\mu\right]^{1/q} \geq \int |f| d\mu$$ where the last inequality is from Holder's inequality. Now taking the $\log$ on both sides we have $$\log\|f\|_{q} = \frac{1}{q}\log\int |f|^q d\mu \geq \frac{1}{q}\int \log |f|^q d\mu = \int \log |f|d\mu$$ where the last inequality follows from Jensen's inequality.

Attempted proof b.) We know that $\log x \leq x - 1$ for every $x > 0$, also we have that $$\log\|f\|_{q} = \frac{1}{q}\log\left(\int |f|^q d\mu\right) \leq \frac{1}{q}\left(\int |f|^q - 1 d\mu\right)$$ Now suppose $q\rightarrow 0$ then for $\frac{|f|^q - 1}{q}\rightarrow \log|f|$ so by the monotone convergence theorem the result follows.

Attempted proof c.) If we exponentiate the result from part a.) we have $$\liminf_{q\rightarrow 0}\|f\|_{q} \geq \exp(\int \log |f|)$$ Then exponentiating the result from part b.) we get $$\limsup_{q\rightarrow 0}\|f\|_{q} \leq \exp(\int \log |f|)$$ thus we get the desired result $$\lim\limits_{q\rightarrow 0}\|f\|_{q} = \exp(\int \log |f|)$$

Not sure if this is right will edit more as I progress. Any suggestions or comments is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For part a.), a quick note: we don't *multiply* both sides by $\log$.  Instead, we take the $\log$ of both sides.  The reason the inequality is still preserved is because $\log$ is an increasing function.  So this shows that $\log( ||f||_{q}) \geq \log(\int |f| \,d\mu)$.  But now you have to justify why $\log(\int |f|\,d\mu) \geq \int \log |f| \,d\mu$ (if this inequality is actually true -- it seems like this is the direction you were going in).

Comment: I see thanks for the comment, I will edit it soon

Comment: Now that I think about it, why is $||f||_{q} \geq \int |f|\,d\mu$?

Comment: It is a fact from Hoelders Inequality I believe, I could be wrong

Comment: Yes, it does follow from Holder's inequality since the measure space has finite measure 1. The first thing I would try with this problem is to try and use Jensen's inequality (the version for which $\log$ applies with).

Comment: Consider an interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, and functions $f,g:I\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ then $\int_{I}|f(x)g(x)|dx\leq \left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_{I}|g(x)|^q dx\right)^{1/q}$

Comment: @Yeldarbskich Does Jensen's inequality imply that $\log\int |f| \geq \int \log |f|$?

Comment: Jensen's Inequality for Concave Functions:  "Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a concave function and assume that $\mu(X)=1$. Then $$f\left( \int_X g \, d\mu \right) \geq \int_X f \circ g \, d\mu$$ For convex functions just change the direction of the inequality."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $(a)$ follows immediately from Jensen's inequality.

For $(b)$ recall that $\log x \le x - 1$ for every $x > 0$, then $$\log\|f\|_q = \frac 1q\log\Big(\int_X|f|^q\Big)\le \frac 1q\Big(\int_X|f|^q - 1\Big).$$ Moreover it is known that $\frac{|f|^q - 1}{q} \to \log|f|$ as $q \to 0$, so that by the MCT the convergence in $(b)$ is proved.

For $(c)$: exponentiating the result in $(a)$ gives $\liminf_{q\to 0}\|f\|_q \ge e^{\int\log|f|}$ while exponentiating the one in $(b)$ we obtain $\limsup_{q \to 0}\|f\|_q\le e^{\int\log|f|}$.

Comment: Can you show me how part a follows from Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @Wolfgang $\log\|f\|_q = \frac 1q\log\int|f|^q \ge \frac 1q\int\log|f|^q = \int\log|f|$

Comment: what does LDCT stand for? I am guessing DCT is dominated convergence theorem

Comment: L stands for Lebesgue. Anyway, that's probably not correct, or at least I can't justify it anymore. This is not a problem since you can pass to the limit with the monotone convergence theorem. Sorry about that!

Comment: no problem, so is your part b.) not correct?

Comment: It is correct now, I just applied the wrong convergence theorem before :)

Comment: got it thanks again

Comment: I think $\|f\|_{q}$ is missing in your last statement of part c.)?

Comment: Also, could you show me why exponentiating the result from a.) yields $\liminf$ is that a definition I forgot?

Comment: $\|f\|_q = e^{\log\|f\|_q} \ge e^{\int\log|f|}$. Now take the $\liminf_q$ on both sides :)